# No such method running forEach in Scala job on Apache Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I'm running a very simple Scala job on Apache Spark 2.4.5 and when I try and iterate over the columns in a DataFrame and print there names I get the following stack trace correlating to the line where I try and call the for each.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: scala.Predef$.refArrayOps([Ljava/lang/Object;)[Ljava/lang/Object;
at SimpleApp$.main(SimpleApp.scala:10)
at SimpleApp.main(SimpleApp.scala)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.JavaMainApplication.start(SparkApplication.scala:52)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:845)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:161)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:184)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:86)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$$anon$2.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:920)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:929)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
```

I am running Apache Spark in Docker using this image: bde2020/spark-master:2.4.5-hadoop2.7
I am compiling my app using scalaVersion := "2.12.11"

Full application code is:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.{Row, SparkSession}

object SimpleApp {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val file = "/spark/jobs/job1/data/test.json"
    val spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("Simple Application Scala").getOrCreate()
    val testData = spark.read.json(file)
    println("prints fine")
    testData.columns.foreach(x => println(x))
    spark.stop()
  }
```

build.sbt file is

```
name := "spark-scala"

version := "0.1"

scalaVersion := "2.12.11"

libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % "2.4.5"
```

I am at a loss, I have checked and checked I am running the correct versions of things but suspect I must of missed something!

Comment: could try adding `spark-core` dependency.. `
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "2.4.5"
`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75947449/run-a-scala-code-jar-appear-nosuchmethoderrorscala-predef-refarrayops

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After much head banging discovered the image actually uses Scala 2.11.12 which is deprecated with Spark 2.4.5! Obvious in hindsight, all working now.

Answer (score 0):

You are not setting **spark-core** in your dependencies.